# Relation “users” does not exist. PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a users table, I see it in pgadmin4, but for some reason when I use psql and try to run list users, I get the following error:

Relation “users” does not exist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will happen if the psql user does not have **schema level privileges**. This error message can be misleading.

To solve this issue, try connecting using psql with an **admin** user and run:

1.

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO <non-admin-user>;
```

2. 

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO <non-admin-user>;
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to put table name in **quotes**.
And, it is **case sensitive**:

```
SELECT * FROM "Users";
```

Comment: Adding quotes if there is a capital letter

Comment: Thanks bro, you saved me! Kudos for you!

Answer (score 1):

I've add new Schema (and remove there my user table) in database so my request was

```
SELECT "role" FROM "user" ...
```

But now should be with schema name

```
SELECT "role" FROM "schemaName"."user" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

none of the solution mentioned here worked for me untill i wrote the query thus

```
SELECT * FROM public."Users";
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score -5):

In case of automated test, setting a delay after migrations do the job:

```
setTimeout(() => {
   // queries
}, 1000);
```

Maybe it is the delay for the database to be done.
The automated test is multithread in my case.